# SQL Azure / SQL Server 2008 - Stored procedure - do not insert if error at any point

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, transactions, azure-sql-database

I have quite a simple question I think, but I need a definitive answer. I can't think of way to test out my ideas because it depends on a transient error (out of my control)

SQL Azure is prone to transient errors, timeouts, rejected connections etc. Sometimes on opening the connection, other times when executing a query.

I am inserting a row into SQL Azure via a stored procedure (it's basically a messaging system, so each message should be sent/inserted only once).

If a transient error occurs, my system waits a few seconds, then tries again ... repeating until the stored procedure executes without any errors.

I need the stored procedure to either insert the row and confirm to me that it has been inserted OR to fail completely and NOT insert it.

At the minute, I'm finding that when the database is going through a really bad patch, a message can end up being sent several times.

What would a system that deals with financial transactions do?

Since it's jut one insert statement, am I right in thinking wrapping it in a transaction would have no effect?

Can anyone clarify for me or even point me to some documentation I should read to figure it out myself?

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: What is the unique business key on the table? I don't mean an IDENTITY: that isn't a business key. You need this to identify duplicates...

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I fail to see your point

Comment: @gbn, thanks, I ended up adding a business key as you suggested and using this to check for duplicates

Comment: Did you read the link? I meant you shouldn't use signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the suggestion by gbn, I added an extra key, not an identity, that I could use to identify duplicates and check on this before inserting

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is more than just one insert in procedure (some selects after insert?)
You can start transaction in application. that way- if you do commit transaction in application and it succeeds, everything is done.